# How to create WinUI3 C++ app with MFC Doc/View architecture

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi, winui-3

I have a MFC app with Doc/View architecture and it is created with multiple-document interface. I want to use latest UI from WinUI3 so want to convert the MFC app to WinUI3. How can I go about it? If I start from scratch, what support do I have from WinUI for doc/view architecture that is inbuilt in MFC? Can I use Opengl to render graphics in a WinUI3 app?

Comment: *"what support do I have from WinUI for doc/view architecture that is inbuilt in MFC?"* - None, at the code level. You can use data binding in XAML that solves the same problem, but it's pretty much a rewrite. *"Can I use Opengl to render graphics in a WinUI3 app?"* - Possibly, but it will be harder than from MFC or a Windows API application.

Comment: There are so many limitations with new frameworks like UWP/WinUI. Are these not meant for serious app development? Are these for simple apps only? There are not many good options when it comes to C++ on Windows.

Comment: For instance I want to develop a CAD application. So I want to render 3D model in the view and change this view based on data in doc. I do not think xaml data binding is very helpful here. So I am stuck with old MFC.

Comment: UWP is a platform, not a framework. Its specific limitations serve a purpose that once had a higher priority: Securing the system while allowing it to run 3rd-party programs. As for the specific limitations of WinUI, it's hard to make any recommendations without knowing what those are. If you want to gradually transition an MFC application to use WinUI, you can do that (with WinUI3, or XAML Islands for WinUI2).

Comment: For a CAD application, XAML data binding is no less useful than MFC's document/view architecture. Neither one is of particular utility here.

Comment: I would have to disagree with you on MFC being less useful since I have worked on a major CAD application using Doc/View. And it was not no-useful. Any particular reason you say MFC is also same as WinUI? Because I think support from Doc/View to store data/render view/ change properties is a great out of box support. How difficult it is to achieve the same using WinUI if no out of box support available.

Comment: That's not at all what I'm saying. I'm saying that you don't get much use out of the document/view architecture in MFC. You're essentially using the **tiny** part of the interface that grants you access to the document. The exact same access you get from binding a model to any given view. Other than that, you're doing all your rendering manually anyway, true for MFC and whatever else you opt to use today, be that WinUI, DirectComposition/Windows.UI.Composition, Direct2D, Direct3D, etc. If you need to find out which technology fits your needs, you'll have to familiarize yourself with them.

Comment: You say - "Its specific limitations serve a purpose that once had a higher priority" So is this priority no longer the case? And it is being replaced with something else?

Comment: Microsoft have lost interest in supporting the UWP, as evidenced by WinUI3 no longer supporting UWP applications. The only reason to target the UWP is if you're supporting multiple devices, such as HoloLens, XBox, Windows 10 Mobile, in addition to Windows 10/11. The UWP isn't getting replaced by anything as far as I know. It just disappears. You can continue to write desktop applications now, same as before the advent of the UWP. Use the [Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/) is being hip is important.

Comment: I was looking for WinUI 3 samples for apps that render/interact with 3d data but could not find. So asked the question here. Would you be able to point to an example for this - "The exact same access you get from binding a model to any given view."?

Comment: A CAD application is pretty much entirely a custom UI implementation, regardless of the framework used. I'm not aware of any WinUI3 samples that showcase custom 3D rendering and interaction. There's no technical reason that would prevent you from implementing one, it's just not something where WinUI is of much help. It's squarely focused around data binding, adaptive layouting, UI scriptability through XAML, change propagation. Displaying and updating data, essentially. None of that is very helpful in a CAD application.